# get all pages page by custom field

Tags: wordpress

I am try to get all my page in wordpress that have a custom field like this.

```
  $query = new WP_Query(array('meta_key=showHome&meta_value=true&post_type=page'));
       print_r(count($query));
```

But this return only one element!

any idea to how get all pages with meta_key=showHome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove meta_value=true from query string

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('meta_key=showHome&post_type=page'));
       print_r(count($query));
```